# Waiting for liveData observe and return result

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm new in Kotlin Mvvm and I have some problems with using live data Observe,
how can we observe live data in a function and return results?

my viewModel

```
fun fetchDictionary(word: String): LiveData<Dictionary> {
    return dictionaryRepository.fetchWordDef(word)
}
```

my fragment:

```
private fun someMethode(): List<LearningWordWithDef> {
    ...
    val result = mutableListOf<LearningWordWithDef>()
    for (word in wordsList) {
        val liveDataDef = viewModel.fetchDictionary(word)

        liveDataDef.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { dictionary ->
        result.add(
            LearningWordWithDef(
                word,
                dictionary
            )
        )
        liveDataDef.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
    }
    return result
}
```

obviously, this method always returns an empty list but this is what I looking for, waiting until all observes finish.

thanks for helping and sorry for my english

Comment: You simply can't do that. The data is coming sometime in the future, and it will possibly be arriving multiple times, so it doesn't make sense to immediately return it from a function. You need to use the data inside the observer, or your function can take a callback parameter instead of returning a value, and you can call that callback with the result in your observer.

Comment: Since you have a bunch of LiveData, you can't really use the data inside the observer. LiveData is for simple cases, but this isn't a simple case. You may want to change your repository to use suspend functions and Flows instead, so you can fetch all these items in parallel.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Can you send me a link for guidance?

Comment: Coroutines are a big topic and have a steep learning curve. If you aren't already very familiar with them, I recommend reading the official Kotlin documentation on them, and also any Medium articles about them written by Roman Elizarov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick example to show how this can be done with suspend functions in your case.

In your DAO and the corresponding repository function, change `fetchDictionary` to be a suspend function that directly returns the word instead of a LiveData of the word.

Then in your ViewModel, you can do the following to fetch all these words in parallel:

```
suspend fun fetchLearningWordWithDef(words: Iterable<String>): List<LearningWordWithDef> = coroutineScope {
    words.map { word -> async { 
        LearningWordWithDef(word, dictionaryRepository.fetchWordDef(it) 
    } }.awaitAll()
}
```

Then in your fragment, wherever you need to fetch and use these words, you start a coroutine:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    //...
    val learningWordWithDefList = viewModel.fetchLearningWordWithDef(wordList)

    // Use the list here inside the coroutine
}
```

Comment: I love your quick ex, tnks.